# Similar data sources matching architecture

Tags: c#, algorithm, architecture, match

**The problem:**

I am developing a system which requires 3 different data sources to be combined automatically.

So lets say we have 3 types of objects: 
Object A (from source A):

```
int Id
string Name
int ObjectB_Id
```

Object B (from source B):

```
int Id
string Name
int ObjectC_Id
```

Object C (from source C):

```
int Id
string Name
```

**Each of these objects are provided by their own unique sources which may send new data at any time.**

All of these are saved in their own local datasets (A, B and C).

**The goal:**
I need to have a combined dataset as such:

```
int Id
int? ObjectA_Id
int? ObjectB_Id
int? ObjectC_Id
```

That is populated with Ids from all objects. This dataset needs to be updated automatically with new or updated matches if sources A,B or C sends any new data.
Objects can be matched by the common Name field, or if an object has a foreign object Id, this can also be used (ObjectB_Id, ObjectC_Id in this case).

My first idea of this was something like this, which was followed by a problem:

Usual case scenario of my solution:

- Source C sends a new Object C. It matches with Object A from Dataset A (by Name), but is unable to match with any Object B, and it is
  placed in the combined dataset, although with incomplete data.
- Source B sends a new Object B. It matches with Object C from Dataset C (by ObjectC_Id), but is unable to match with any Object A (let's say the Names are slightly different). This is then compared to any of the items in the combined dataset, and it finds that it can make a connection to the previous entry by a common ObjectC_Id property. These 2 entries are merged in the dataset.

Problem with this solution:

- All updates from each
  source requires other datasets to be available for matching - so if
  Source C sends a new update, then to try and match with both datasets
  A and B it requires them to be fetched from the database. (all of
  these may hold ~200k records). This is very slow.

Comment: Are you trying to create a 4th data set which is combination of the other 3 ? Or trying to sync all datasets with each other ?  Another question is if you want to create different data set why exactly do you need that? I am asking this because there might be different ways other than combining.

Comment: @ali.turan My main goal is to sync them together - I need to be able to get data from all 3 datasets by just one id. Dataset 4 was just to map them all together.